# Is there a better way to change style based on screen size on react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Im using Material UI on my react app and I'm using useMediaQuery and useTheme from mui. This is the code I have right now. Is there a better way to optimize less code? There are only a few style changes between the 2 codes.

```
const MainPage = () => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const isMatch = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'))
    return (
        <div className='mainPage'>
            {
                isMatch ? (
                    <>
                        <Box sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignContent: "center", flexDirection: "column", padding: "60px 10px 10px 10px" }}>
                            <Box component="img" src={LandingImage} sx={{ width: "100%" }} />
                            <Box sx={{ paddingTop: 8 }}>
                                <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 26, fontWeight: "bold", fontFamily: "sans-serif", textAlign: "center", paddingBottom: 5 }}>About us</Typography>
                            </Box>
                        </Box>
                    </>
                ) : (
                    <>
                        <Box sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignContent: "center", flexDirection: "row", paddingTop: 20 }}>
                            <Box component="img" src={LandingImage} />
                            <Box sx={{ width: 700, paddingTop: 8 }}>
                                <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 30, fontWeight: "bold", fontFamily: "sans-serif", textAlign: "center", paddingBottom: 5 }}>About us</Typography>
                            </Box>
                        </Box>
                    </>
                )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the structure of JSX for mobile / desktop is the same, you could drop one of those two JSX templates, build a variable to store component configuration based on `isMatch` and pass this variable into component template.

```
const MainPage = () => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const isMatch = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'))

    // Subset of props, to illustrate the idea.
    const config = isMatch ? {fontSize: 26} : {fontSize: 30};

    // Here only root <Box/> is configured, but you can configure all the nested components the same way.
    return (
        <div className='mainPage'>
          <Box sx={config}>[...]</Box>
        </div>
    )
}
```

(Same with components nested inside `<Box/>` - the idea is the same - declare some variables with value based on your state and pass them to JSX declaration)

Comment: I like your way since it can be used in multiple components.

Comment: Side note: I'm not a MUI framework expect (actually never used it before). Maybe there are better patterns for coping with responsive breakpoints in this particular tool.

Answer (score 8):

There really is no need to do a media query like this, as the `sx` prop provides per-breakpoint customization if you want it.

Notice, for example, the `flexDirection` styling on the first Box component. Everything up to the `md` breakpoint gets `column`, then it becomes `row`.

```
const MainPage = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <div className='mainPage'>
      <Box sx={{ 
        display: "flex", 
        justifyContent: "center", 
        alignContent: "center", 
        flexDirection: { xs: "column", md: "row" },
        padding: { xs: "60px 10px 10px 10px", md: "20px 0 0 0" } 
      }}>
        <Box 
          component="img" 
          src={LandingImage} 
          sx={{ 
            width: { xs: "100%", md: 'unset' }
        }}/>
        <Box sx={{ 
          paddingTop: 8,
          width: { md: 700 }
        }}>
          <Typography 
            sx={{ 
              fontSize: { xs: 26, md: 30 }, 
              fontWeight: "bold", 
              fontFamily: "sans-serif", 
              textAlign: "center", 
              paddingBottom: 5 
          }}>
            About us
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </div>
  )
}
```

https://mui.com/system/basics/#responsive-values

Answer (score 0):

Mui has breakpoints shorthand syntax, as you can check [here](https://mui.com/system/basics/#responsive-values).

So, for example, your code will also work with:

```js
const MainPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="mainPage">
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignContent: "center",
          flexDirection: ["column", "column", "row"],
          paddingTop: ["60px 10px 10px 10px", "60px 10px 10px 10px", 20]
        }}
      >
        <Box component="img" />
        <Box sx={{ width: ["unset", "unset", 700], paddingTop: 8 }}>
          <Typography
            sx={{
              fontSize: [26, 26, 30],
              fontWeight: "bold",
              fontFamily: "sans-serif",
              textAlign: "center",
              paddingBottom: 5
            }}
          >
            About us
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the example above i use the Breakpoints as an array and `mui` docs says:

> The second option is to define your breakpoints as an array, from the smallest to the largest breakpoint.

So imagine that array positions would be: `[xs, sm, md, lg, xl]` and the breakpoints are equivalent to `theme.breakpoints.up`.

Another way to do it is use Breakpoints as an object:

**Simple example**

```
<Box
   sx={{
      width: {
         xs: 100, // theme.breakpoints.up('xs')
         sm: 200, // theme.breakpoints.up('sm')
         md: 300, // theme.breakpoints.up('md')
         lg: 400, // theme.breakpoints.up('lg')
         xl: 500, // theme.breakpoints.up('xl')
      },
   }}
>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several options. The first is to create a style object in javascript, which can be interacted with like normal javascript. You are already doing this in-line, but if we do it in the code above, we can make it dynamic.

```
const myOuterBoxStyle = {
  display: "flex", 
  justifyContent: "center", 
  alignContent: "center",
  flexDirection: "row",
  paddingTop: 20
}
if (isMatch) {
  myOuterBoxStyle.flexDirection = "column";
  myOuterBoxStyle.paddingTop = undefined;
  myOuterBoxStyle.padding = "60px 10px 10px 10px";
}
```

Once you do all of the dynamic styling you need, you can make a single return for your component and simply put

```
<Box sx={{myOuterBoxStyle}}>
```

The other option is to make a seperate CSS sheet and import it, and then use classes. Something like

```
.outer-box {
display: "flex";
justify-content: "center";
align-content: "center";
}

.is-match {
flex-direction: "column";
padding: "60px 10px 10px 10px"
}
```

And then you can either add the `is-match` class or, perhaps, the `is-not-match` class depending.

The final option is to use a third-party package that does most of this for you, like [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/)

Comment: While this can work with the if statement only if you are trying to change the style for one component.

Comment: Style objects can be passed as props, or even as a context, but you can also do more universal styling by making a css sheet on your App.js or your index.js. Check my edit please for the other options I mentioned and forgot to put on.